# Can we attach some variables to route path in ruby on rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner in ruby-on-rails and I struggled for hours to do this:

There is one variable **X** in a html page **Page1** of one controller **C1** in my application. And I want to link to anther route path **path1** with that variable **X** so that I can do something with that variable **X** in the controller action **act1** corresponding to that route path **path1**.

In my situation is:

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to 'Enroll', enroll_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
```

This code is in the view page html and I want to link_to enroll_path with the variable **course**

```
post '/enroll', to: 'enrollments#enroll'
```

This is the enroll path route

```
def enroll
  enrollment = Enrollment.new(user_id: current_user.id, course_id: course[id])
  enrollment.save
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

This is action that corresponds enroll path and I want use the variable **course** in it.

I have tried to attach the variable course directly to the enroll_path, Like this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Enroll', enroll_path(course), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

but it did not work out.

How should I do to solve this?

Comment: `enroll_path(course)` leads to something like this `/enroll/course_id` route. Do you have it in your routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<%= link_to 'Enroll', enroll_path(course_id: course.id), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

I believe you will have to change the controller line to this

```
enrollment = Enrollment.new(user_id: current_user.id, course_id: params[:course_id])
```

This part `(course_id: course.id)` sends `course_id` as a param, so in the controller you can access its value by looking for `params[:course_id]`.

Comment: Thanks, it works!! Does that mean I can regard route path as a hash and I can add key-value into it, then I can refer it by calling params in other action?

Comment: @ZhidongLiu I updated the answer to include that info.  Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark